# String array suddenly losses stored values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using a `dat` file to store underscore separated values and comma separated values at the same time but every time I want to get the values of a the second `String[]` called basics in order to set values of another object but it suddenly resets it's size and stores values to the first splitted one.

String data in this case would be like:

```
String data = "0234_ADMIN_12-Jun-2022 21:58:59,5635_PAL_16.0_54";
```

---

```java
private void cargarNotas() {
    try {
        BufferedReader leerNotas = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(regNotas));
        String data = leerNotas.readLine();
        while (data!= null) {
            String[] items = data.split(",");
            String[] basics = items[0].trim().split("_");
            System.out.println(basics.length);
            NotaDeVenta tempNota = new NotaDeVenta();
            tempNota.setnoNota(basics[0]);
            tempNota.setUsuario(basics[1]);
            tempNota.setFecha(FORMAT.parse(basics[2]));
            String[] values = null;
            for(int i = 0;i<items.length-1;i++) {
                values = items[i+1].split("_");
                ItemParaMovimientos tempItem = new ItemParaMovimientos(Control.getProducto(values[1]),Integer.parseInt(values[3]));
                tempNota.addItem(tempItem);
            }
            Control.addNota(tempNota);
            data = leerNotas.readLine();
        }
        leerNotas.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: length Output]

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking, but you do know that each time around your while loop you set `basics` to a new value?

Comment: What happens if `items` or `basics` have a length of 1 (index 0) but you attempt to access a value higher than 0? Correct, you get an index out of bounds exception. Think about these lines, and what happens when `items` and `basics` have a length that is not what you expect, for example `basics[1]` or `basics[2]` when the array may only have a length of 1 `tempNota.setFecha(FORMAT.parse(basics[2]));`, and `i+1` here `values = items[i+1].split("_");` when the length of items will only be 1 (or index 0) with the example input string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: I second what @sorifiend said above. You'll need to inspect your data and handle scenarios where your array size = 1. For example, in your output, your System.out.println() statement is first resulting in 3 as basics.length when things are working fine and then 1 as basics.length when you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because there is no index 1 or 2 to read from.